# Plot key count per unique value count in pandas

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I have a set of data from which I want to plot the *number of keys* per *unique id count*  (x=unique_id_count, y=key_count), and I'm trying to learn how to take advantage of `pandas`.

In this case:

unique_ids 1 = key count 2

unique_ids 2 = key count 1

```
from pandas import *
key_items = ("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
id_data = ("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X")

df = DataFrame({'keys': key_items, 'ids': id_data})
```

I've managed to mangle the data into what I want by pulling out the data from the dataframe and restructuring it, and rebuilding a new dataframe.  In this case it's probably better to do it all in python without pandas...

```
unique_values = defaultdict(list)
for items in df.itertuples(index=False):
    key = items[1]
    v = items[0]
    unique_values[key].append(v)

unique_values_count = {}
for k, values in unique_values.iteritems():
    unique_values_count[k] = [len(set(values))]

# reformat for plotting
key_col = ("a", "b", "c")
id_col = [unique_values_count[k][0] for k in key_col]



df2 = DataFrame({"keys":key_col, "unique_id_count": id_col})
df2.groupby("unique_id_count").size().plot(kind="bar")
```

Is there a better way to do this more directly using the initial dataframe?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
s = df.groupby("keys").ids.agg(lambda x:len(x.unique()))
pd.value_counts(s).plot(kind="bar")
```

Comment: This can be simplified a bit: `s` can be computed without lambdas using the pandas `nunique` function like so: `s = df.groupby("keys").agg(Series.nunique)`

Answer (score 54):

How about just directly use `value_counts()`

```
pd.value_counts(df['ids']).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: gives error `<lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'height'`, fix that worked for me is `df['ids'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')`, pandas version 0.22

Comment: Awesome. This also names the bars, ex: X, Y. Thanks a lot :). With previous answer I wasn't able to see that.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is -

```
df['your_column'].count_values().plot.bar(rot=0)
```

If you wish to limit the number of bars if the values are too many -

```
df['your_column'].count_values()[:no_of_values].plot.bar(rot=0)
```